# Are the output part of the source code of Linux commands like ls,pwd,find defined like return or printf?

Tags: linux, function, shell, command, printf

In linux shell, if we type "ls",we will get something like "/Desktop,/Music...".

It is clearly that when we execute some similar functions in interactive environments of some dynamic programming languages like haskell, the output of the environments are the results of functions. Although every shown result is implicitly transformed by "print", the outputs were once results of functions.

Well, I just want to know whether the outputs of linux commands are IO actions or they are results of functions.

Comment: Your question is not precise enough, and (to get a good answer) you could study the source code of most Linux utilities, since they are free software; see http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ etc; you could also use `strace` to find out what syscalls are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C language breaks programs into functions. Most of the source-code for utilities like ls, find, pwd, etc, are written in C - either as part of the shell ("bash" or some such) - the shell is also typically written in C, or as a separate program.

You could of course, given the right bindings to the C kernel code, write the entire Linux utilities suite in lisp, haskell, ocaml or any other language that has sufficient capabilities (most of it is about string handling, which the vast majority of languages can do).

However, functional languages, are supposed to have "true functions", that is, a function should not have any side-effects. Per definition, writing to a file, reading a file or printing to the screen, is a side-effect - it affects things outside of the function itself and the result is not what is returned from the function. So in that sense, C is not a functional programming language. It has function  which quite often, has side-effects.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, however I was not asking why it is C. I mean whether the outputs in shell are IO actions of commands or the results of commands as functions.

Comment: And the answer to that is "Yes". They are commands in the shell script. The shell script functionality is produced as "functions" (written in C, most likely, but could be any language as long as it produces the desirable functionality - `emacs` for example is largely written in Lisp). So you are trying to split hairs, and when you succeed, you try to split it again - eventually it all comes down to machine instructions and operations in a processor. It's just a case of "how do we describe, in a human readable way what the machine should do". The rest is religion/philosophical aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Can't a function initiate IO activity?

The basic linux/Unix utilties all are written in the C language, and use a wide library of functions to gather information. Some of those functions are likely to initiate disk reads and other I/O. The output is typically generated using the `printf` function, with appropriate format string and arguments to match. Again, more I/O.

IHTH.

Comment: Could you tell the differences between "ls | grep "name"" and "grep(ls(),"name");". Here we assume that grep is of "string grep(string, string)" and ls() is "string ls(void)"

Comment: This is getting into the area of "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin". If you really need to know this sort of information, the only way you'll find it is to develop your own hypotheses, create small binary tests, and then test and observe the outputs. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to answer this question to give you the details you want to know.

Of course they are performing IO operations (reading files, writing files, writing to stdout – which is also a file), but they are certainly also performing work in functions (formatting output and whatnot)

Comment: As the commands like ls, pwd can be piped into another command,I guess they should be performing IO actions.But are all of the commands perform like this?